# Homeomorphism from two open sets

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $f:Y\rightarrow X$ be a continuous map. Let $V_1,V_2\subset Y$ open sets and $U\subset X$ open set such that $f:V_i\rightarrow U$ is a homeomorphism for $i=1,2$. Is it true that $V_1\cap V_2\neq\emptyset$ $\Rightarrow$ $V_1=V_2$?

What if f is a covering map?

Comment: A map from $\{1, 2, 3\}$ to $\{1, 2\},$ $1 \mapsto 1, 2 \mapsto 2, 3 \mapsto 1.$ $V_1 = \{1, 2\}, V_2 = \{2, 3\}.$

Comment: That's a nice counterexample, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true, not even for covering maps. As an example, let $X = \{1,2\}$ with the discrete topology, $Y = X \times X$ and $f : X \times X \to X, f(x,x') = x$. This is a two-sheeted covering map. Let $V_1 = \{(1,1), (2,1)\}$ and $V_2 = \{(1,1),(2,2)\}$. Both are mapped by $f$ homeomorphically onto $U = X$, but $V_1 \ne V_2$ and $V_1 \cap V_2 \ne \emptyset$.

Comment: Oh, that’s true, thank you for the answer. But what I was thinking about covering maps was $V_1$ and $V_2$ as two sheets of $U$ and then it’s obvious that nonempty intersection implies $V_1=V_2$.